# USPTO WebADS missing the date - is this okay?

Tags: uspto

Given the USPTO web-based ADS form, the final part of the form is this:

[image: WebADS form]

Notice there is no date field. The generated PDF then looks like this:

[image: missing date field]

Do I have to edit the PDF myself to add the date? Is this sufficient for the USPTO as is? Should that E-signature be all fancy and cursive in the PDF render?

Comment: It’s been a few years since I filled anything-I’ll research the date question. You couldn’t type it in just like you typed in the signature etc? Regarding Signature - No nothing automatically cursive happens to the eSignature.

Comment: Hi, no, there is no web field for date. The `WebADS.pdf` that is generated is not editable, and is automatically included in the Attach Documents tab in EFS-web. I'd have to install some trial software to edit the PDF, so I ask this question first. Thanks for your interest and reply.

Comment: There are a few ways to get a valid ADS filed but WebADS should not require any hand editing. Using WebADS gets the data directly into the USPTO database without humans there retyping.

Comment: Thanks. And, agreed. I tried to edit the WebADS.pdf just now to add a date with a trial PDF software to be careful. Saved. Uploaded. Reviewed. A warning that the ADS is not "field editable" showed up. That's that, then.